# How does one find the minimum polynomial for functions of the primitive element

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I’m working on the following question.

Let $f(x) = x^3-x+1$ with root $\alpha$. Find the minimum polynomial for $\beta = 2 - 3\alpha + 2\alpha^2$.

My question is about how you might go about finding the minimum polynomial for $\beta$ and how, in general, one might find the minimum polynomial for equations of a primitive element.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: express $\beta^2$ and $\beta^3$ as linear combinations of $1,\alpha,\alpha^2$. Together with $1$ and $\beta$, this gives you four linear combinations of those three quantities; that means you can use linear algebra to find a linear combination of $1,\beta,\beta^2,\beta^3$ that equals $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Since it is an extension of prime degree $3$ either $\beta$ is rational (and an integer since it is an algebraic integer) or its minimal polynomial has degree $3$.

We know it is the latter case because $\Bbb{Q}[\alpha]=\Bbb{Q}\oplus\alpha\Bbb{Q}\oplus\alpha^2\Bbb{Q}$.

Then the minmial polynomial is $\det(B-tI)$ where $B$ is the matrix of the multiplication by $\beta$ on $\Bbb{Q}\oplus\alpha\Bbb{Q}\oplus\alpha^2\Bbb{Q}\cong \Bbb{Q}^3$. In this basis the matrix $A$ of the multiplication by $\alpha$ is the companion matrix of its minimal polynomial and $B=2I-3A+2A^2$.

Comment: It might be worth adding (as an answer to the last part) that in general, when $\beta=g(\alpha)$, one computes the *minimal* polynomial of $g(A)$ where $A$ is the companion matrix of $f$.